# Assign a value from dictionary to the list and convert the list to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a list:

```
FuseValues = {'K0A': 0.11, 'K0B': 0.04, 'K0C': 0.07, 'K0D': 0.11, 'K1A': 0.09, 'K1B': 0.05, 'K1C': 0.03, 'K1D': 0.05, 'K2A': 0.05, 'K2B': 0.04, 'K2C': 0.05, 'K2D': 0.08, 'K3A': 0.08, 'K3B': 0.08, 'K3C': 0.07, 'K3D': 0.11}
Doc_A = [['207', '72', '232', '47', '220', '53', '87', '152', '215', '56', '99', '96', '65', '139', '5', '85', '127', '38', '129', '78', '51', '170', '28', '122', '71'], ['235', '91', '39', '124', '199', '248', '196', '175', '239', '125', '229', '164', '94', '22', '121', '75', '17', '193', '184', '179', '224', '158', '115', '79', '58'], ['41', '105', '80', '59', '173', '151', '42', '8', '128', '204', '21', '213', '16', '116', '246', '126', '195', '24', '25', '144', '178', '23', '155', '104', '10'], ['212', '223', '107', '243', '197', '225', '123', '167', '90', '69', '64', '20', '145', '200', '30', '222', '136', '43', '141', '57', '97', '77', '172', '82', '98']]
```

I want the output as a dictionary with the values of `K0A` assigned to first list, `K1A`to the second, and so on  in the list A, like below:

```
Output_Doc_A = {{'207':0.11, '72':0.11, '232':0.11, '47':0.11, '220':0.11, '53':0.11, '87':0.11, '152':0.11, '215':0.11, '56':0.11, '99':0.11, '96':0.11, '65':0.11, '139':0.11, '5':0.11, '85':0.11, '127':0.11, '38':0.11, '129':0.11, '78':0.11, '51':0.11, '170':0.11, '28':0.11, '122':0.11, '71':0.11},{'235':0.09, '91':0.09, '39':0.09, '124':0.09, '199':0.09, '248':0.09, '196':0.09, '175':0.09, '239':0.09, '125':0.09, '229':0.09, '164':0.09, '94':0.09, '22':0.09, '121':0.09, '75':0.09, '17':0.09, '193':0.09, '184':0.09, '179':0.09, '224':0.09, '158':0.09, '115':0.09, '79':0.09, '58':0.09}{...and so on}}
```

I tried a lot but couldn't figure out a possible solution to this. Can anyone please help?

Comment: how about `K0B`? what happens to that? also your expected output is not valid python. you want a list of dictionaries?

Comment: ```K0B``` and others are additional information to be printed in the output. If list of dictionaries is invalid in python, what could be a possible solution? I am still new to python, can you suggest me any idea

Comment: your output that you show is not a list of dictionaries, it looks like a set of dictionaries which is not possible

Comment: I thought of creating another list with values of ```K0A```, ```K1A``` etc. printed as many times as the items in list of A and then merging both list to create a dictionary. Does that work? I do not know how to do that though

Comment: You placed the Output_Doc_A in nested dictionaries. I'm assuming it was supposed to be dictionaries within a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for (not tested), but the question was a little ambiguous so please forgive any errors, put it in the comments and I will amend the code.

```
A_keys = sorted([k for k in FuseValues.keys() if k[-1] == "A"])
Output_Doc_A = []
for i in range(len(A_keys))):
    Output_Doc_A.append(dict.fromkeys(Doc_A[i], FuseValues[A_keys[i]]))
```

Comment: Let me try this out

Comment: You could always `zip` the A_keys and Doc_A to prevent index errors.

Comment: this is not guaranteed to grab the dictionary keys in order FWIW, it is possible if K1A was inserted first in FuseValues or some other order then this would grab them in that order

Comment: @gold_cy added sorted. This accounts for all give that the extracted ones have the same format.

Comment: It worked perfect. And the right fuse values are attached to the document numbers eg: ```'207': 0.15```. Thanks a lot @LarrytheLlama

Comment: @LibinThomas no problem, relieved it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more verbose approach which hopefully helps you understand how this can be solved.

```
final = []

for num in range(len(Doc_A)):  # iterate over the index of Doc_A
    key = f"K{num}A"  # keys increment from K0A to KNA
    try:
        val = FuseValues[key]  # get the value we want for new keys
    except IndexError:  # in the chance the lengths don't match
        continue
    new_keys = Doc_A[num]  # grab the new keys by using index on Doc_A
    tmp = dict()  # create a temporary dictionary
    for nk in new_keys:  # for each of our new keys
        tmp[nk] = val  # set the value of that key in our temp dictionary
    final.append(tmp)  # append the temp dictionary to our final output list
```

We can also reduce the last `for-loop` to a dictionary comprehension as well.

```
for num in range(len(Doc_A)):
    key = f"K{num}A"
    try:
        val = FuseValues[key]
    except IndexError:
        continue
    new_keys = Doc_A[num]
    tmp = {nk: val for nk in new_keys}
    final.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @gold_cy. This is easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with the fromkeys dictionary constructor and zip to pair up values with keys (assuming the keys are in the same order in the dictionary and the Doc_A list):

```
FuseValues = {'K0A': 0.11, 'K0B': 0.04, 'K0C': 0.07, 'K0D': 0.11, 'K1A': 0.09, 'K1B': 0.05, 'K1C': 0.03, 'K1D': 0.05, 'K2A': 0.05, 'K2B': 0.04, 'K2C': 0.05, 'K2D': 0.08, 'K3A': 0.08, 'K3B': 0.08, 'K3C': 0.07, 'K3D': 0.11}
Doc_A = [['207', '72', '232', '47', '220', '53', '87', '152', '215', '56', '99', '96', '65', '139', '5', '85', '127', '38', '129', '78', '51', '170', '28', '122', '71'], ['235', '91', '39', '124', '199', '248', '196', '175', '239', '125', '229', '164', '94', '22', '121', '75', '17', '193', '184', '179', '224', '158', '115', '79', '58'], ['41', '105', '80', '59', '173', '151', '42', '8', '128', '204', '21', '213', '16', '116', '246', '126', '195', '24', '25', '144', '178', '23', '155', '104', '10'], ['212', '223', '107', '243', '197', '225', '123', '167', '90', '69', '64', '20', '145', '200', '30', '222', '136', '43', '141', '57', '97', '77', '172', '82', '98']]

Values_A = (v for k,v in FuseValues.items() if k.endswith("A"))
Output_Doc_A = [ dict.fromkeys(a,v) for a,v in zip(Doc_A,Values_A)]
print(Output_Doc_A)
    
[{'207': 0.11, '72': 0.11, '232': 0.11, '47': 0.11, '220': 0.11, '53': 0.11, '87': 0.11, '152': 0.11, '215': 0.11, '56': 0.11, '99': 0.11, '96': 0.11, '65': 0.11, '139': 0.11, '5': 0.11, '85': 0.11, '127': 0.11, '38': 0.11, '129': 0.11, '78': 0.11, '51': 0.11, '170': 0.11, '28': 0.11, '122': 0.11, '71': 0.11}, {'235': 0.09, '91': 0.09, '39': 0.09, '124': 0.09, '199': 0.09, '248': 0.09, '196': 0.09, '175': 0.09, '239': 0.09, '125': 0.09, '229': 0.09, '164': 0.09, '94': 0.09, '22': 0.09, '121': 0.09, '75': 0.09, '17': 0.09, '193': 0.09, '184': 0.09, '179': 0.09, '224': 0.09, '158': 0.09, '115': 0.09, '79': 0.09, '58': 0.09}, {'41': 0.05, '105': 0.05, '80': 0.05, '59': 0.05, '173': 0.05, '151': 0.05, '42': 0.05, '8': 0.05, '128': 0.05, '204': 0.05, '21': 0.05, '213': 0.05, '16': 0.05, '116': 0.05, '246': 0.05, '126': 0.05, '195': 0.05, '24': 0.05, '25': 0.05, '144': 0.05, '178': 0.05, '23': 0.05, '155': 0.05, '104': 0.05, '10': 0.05}, {'212': 0.08, '223': 0.08, '107': 0.08, '243': 0.08, '197': 0.08, '225': 0.08, '123': 0.08, '167': 0.08, '90': 0.08, '69': 0.08, '64': 0.08, '20': 0.08, '145': 0.08, '200': 0.08, '30': 0.08, '222': 0.08, '136': 0.08, '43': 0.08, '141': 0.08, '57': 0.08, '97': 0.08, '77': 0.08, '172': 0.08, '82': 0.08, '98': 0.08}]
```

You could also do it with starmap (from itertools):

```
from itertools import starmap
Values_A     = (v for k,v in FuseValues.items() if k.endswith("A"))
Output_Doc_A = [*starmap(dict.fromkeys,zip(Doc_A,Values_A))]
```

If the keys are not in the same order but follow the pattern K#A where # is the index in Doc_A, then you can build the list of dictionaries like this:

```
[ dict.fromkeys(a,FuseValues[f'K{i}A']) for i,a in enumerate(Doc_A)]
```